# How to covert string into HTML tag using markDownParser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on an application where I have implemented a simple program that will convert simple text into HTML, for example, user entered **### header** then it will return **`<h3>header</h3>`**. The problem I am facing is whenever I entered some string with space then it doesn't work for me. Here is the example

```
function markdownParser(markdown) {
  const htmlText = markdown
    .replace(/^# (.*$)/gim, '<h1>$1</h1>')
    .replace(/^## (.*$)/gim, '<h2>$1</h2>')
    .replace(/^### (.*$)/gim, '<h3>$1</h3>')
    .replace(/^#### (.*$)/gim, '<h4>$1</h4>')
    .replace(/^##### (.*$)/gim, '<h5>$1</h5>')
    .replace(/^###### (.*$)/gim, '<h6>$1</h6>')
 return htmlText.trim() 
}
```

If I pass #### Muhammad Kamran doesn't return `<h4>Muhammad Kamran</h4>`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the regular expression in the replace method to match a pattern with whitespaces by including \s in the expression.

```
function markdownParser(markdown) {
  const htmlText = markdown
    .replace(/^#\s(.*)$/gim, '<h1>$1</h1>')
    .replace(/^##\s(.*)$/gim, '<h2>$1</h2>')
    .replace(/^###\s(.*)$/gim, '<h3>$1</h3>')
    .replace(/^####\s(.*)$/gim, '<h4>$1</h4>')
    .replace(/^#####\s(.*)$/gim, '<h5>$1</h5>')
    .replace(/^######\s(.*)$/gim, '<h6>$1</h6>')
  return htmlText.trim(); 
}
```

i hope it could help